# 3 monitors on a Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

Is this possible with Nividia GeForce GT 520MX graphics card?

One monitor is connected to VGA port, another monitor to HDMI.
But in the Display -> Screen resolution menu, one of the 3 monitors is always grayed out.

The laptop is Samsung NP 300E7A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but you'll need a separate display driver for the third monitor. I had the same problem and I don't think those nvidia adapters support 3 monitors. I bought a usb to dvi adapter to drive the third display.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your laptop's (and most laptop's) integrated display chipsets can't display on more than two devices at a time, its just a limitation of the hardware.